# How can I reference an ESI URL that includes an encoded HTML entity with Varnish?

Tags: html, encoding, varnish, url-encoding, varnish-4

I am using Varnish 4.1.2, and trying to include ESI content.  Sometimes, the URL for the included content might include encoded HTML entities, such as `&#x27;` (`'`).

For example, I have the following in the HTML returned by my app for the outer shell:

```
<esi:include src="/esi/map/alice&#x27;s%20house"/>
```

This *should* result in an ESI request for a path with 3 segments and no query string, which when fully decoded, result in:

- `esi`
- `map`
- `alice's house`

The apostrophe in the third segment is HTML encoded because it is being transmitted in an HTML document.  The space is URL encoded because it is part of a URL.

However, Varnish seems to not decode the HTML encoded entity before making the ESI request.  It sends a request for `/esi/map/alice&#x27;s%20house`, which is a bad request, because `&` is not legal in the path or a URL.

How can I get Varnish to handle these ESI links properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up posting this question on the Varnish [Github issue tracker](https://github.com/varnishcache/varnish-cache/issues/2034), and it seems the answer is: you can't.

The workaround is to URL-encode the link, to avoid the need for using HTML entities.